# Checking if a given Integer is the first element of a tuple in a list of tuples

Tags: haskell

I have an assignment in which I need to check if a given Int is the first element of any tuple in a list of tuples. For example, if I want to check if `1` is the first element of any tuple on the list `[(2,3), (3,3), (2,7)]` it should return `False`, however, if I want to check if `1` is the first element on the list `[(2,2), (1,2), (3,4)]`, it should return `True`.
This is my attempt:

```
    isFirst :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a,b)] -> Bool
    isFirst _ [] = False
    isFirst x [(y1, y2)] = x == y1
    isFirst x  ((y1, y2):l) = if y1 : isFirst l then True 
                                else False
```

I'm still new to Haskell so I really have no clue if I'm even close to the right solution, Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can modify the function:

```
isFirst :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a,b)] -> Bool
isFirst _ [] = False
isFirst x [(y1, y2)] = x == y1
isFirst x  ((y1, y2):l) = (x == y1) || isFirst x l
```

**What was wrong with the earlier implementation?**

Writing `y1 : isFirst l` means you want to add `y` to the start of the list generated by `isFirst l`. But `isFirst` should return a `Bool`, so that wouldn't work.

**What's the fix?**

Explicitly check for the first tuple, and then recursively call `isFirst` on the rest of the list. Joining the two checks with an OR will be a logically correct operation, since each check returns a `Bool` result.

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of [**`any :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:any) here to check if any of the 2-tuples has a first element that is equal to the one we are looking for:

```
isFirst :: Eq a => a -> [(a,b)] -> Bool
isFirst x ys = any (\(y, _) -> x == y) ys
```

or shorter:

```
isFirst :: Eq a => a -> [(a,b)] -> Bool
isFirst x = any ((==) x . fst)
```